# OWIN Route requires (any) querystring for POST?

Tags: c#, owin, self-hosting

Given the following method in an API Controller in a self-hosted OWIN application:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/foo")]
public HttpResponseMessage Foo([FromBody]SomeClass data)
{
    //...implementation here
}
```

Posting to the following URI's **doesn't** invoke the `Foo()` method:

- `http://localhost:8080/foo`
- `http://localhost:8080/foo/`

Posting to the following URI's **does** invoke the `Foo()` method:

- `http://localhost:8080/foo?`
- `http://localhost:8080/foo?bar`
- `http://localhost:8080/foo?bar=baz`

I want to be able to post to the 'bare' URI `http://localhost:8080/foo`

What am I doing wrong? (Ofcourse I invoked [`MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479134(v=vs.118).aspx) when initializing the service).

---

**Update 1**

Strange. I created the following (self-contained) testcase:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = WebApp.Start("http://+:8080", (appBuilder) =>
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
            config.EnsureInitialized();
        });

        var postdata = new NameValueCollection();
        postdata["data"] = "testing";

        var testurls = new[] {
            "http://localhost:8080/foo",
            "http://localhost:8080/foo/",
            "http://localhost:8080/foo?",
            "http://localhost:8080/foo?x",
            "http://localhost:8080/foo?x=y",
        };

        foreach (var url in testurls)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var w = new WebClient())
                    w.UploadValues(url, postdata);
                Console.WriteLine($"OK  : {url}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"FAIL: {url} ({ex.Message})");
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct MyData
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("foo")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Foo([FromBody]MyData postdata)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"POST: {postdata.Data}");
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
POST: testing
OK  : http://localhost:8080/foo
POST: testing
OK  : http://localhost:8080/foo/
POST: testing
OK  : http://localhost:8080/foo?
POST: testing
OK  : http://localhost:8080/foo?x
POST: testing
OK  : http://localhost:8080/foo?x=y
```

So there's something different in my actual project that breaks this. Now to find the difference...

---

**Update 2**

[Never mind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40133638/215042). The problem was in the (client) application posting to my service, not the service itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my updated question. I'm a dumbass. The problem was in the application posting to my OWIN service, not the OWIN service itself. The code is correct, the client had a bug in the way the URI to post to was built.